# How do I init a spring integration:gateway at startup?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm using spring integration to communicate via active mq. I've got the following config.

```
<integration:channel id="riskApprovalRequestChannel"/>
    <integration:channel id="riskApprovalResponseChannel"/>

    <jms:outbound-gateway id="riskApprovalServiceGateway"
                          request-destination-name="${risk.approval.queue.request}"
                          reply-destination-name="${risk.approval.queue.response}"
                          request-channel="riskApprovalRequestChannel"
                          reply-channel="riskApprovalResponseChannel"
                          connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
                          receive-timeout="1000"/>

    <integration:gateway id="riskApprovalService" service-interface="com.my.ServiceInterface"
                         default-request-channel="riskApprovalRequestChannel"
                         default-reply-channel="riskApprovalResponseChannel"/>
```

This works well except for the 1st request, which is slow. I always hit the 1 second timeout on the 1st request. There's obviously some lazy loading going on somewhere.

My question is, how do I do a full initialisation at start up to avoid the 1st request always timing out?

Cheers,

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably connection establishment that's the issue.

One thing you can do is wrap the vendor ConnectionFactory in a Spring CachingConnectionFactory (good idea to do this anyway, for performance reasons), and call createConnection() during initialization.

There are a number of ways to do that - including injecting the connection factory into some other bean, with an init-method, @PostConstruct method, or an InitializingBean with afterPropertiesSet(); it will be called during context initialization.

This will cause the cache's connection to be eagerly connected.

You might want to do it in a try block, to avoid the application context failing to initialize because the JMS broker is not available (of course messaging will still fail, but the app will be up and ready to connect when the broker is available).

Comment: Russel : I'm already using the Spring CachingConnectinoFactory. Adding init-method="createConnection" did fix things, but I suspect it also leaves an orphaned connection floating around. I ended up using

<bean factory-bean="jmsConnectionFactory" factory-method="createConnection" init-method="close" />

which seems to do the job.

Accepted the answer as it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: There shouldn't be any additional connections, because the CCF uses a single connection (it's a subclass of the SingleConnectionFactory that adds caching of sessions, consumrs, and producers).

Comment: Using a factory bean for eagerly creating the connection is a neat trick. But, as I noted in the other thread, you don't need the init-method - it does nothing since the single connection is retained for reuse.

Comment: Without the need for the close method I think I prefer your initial suggestion which was to use an init method on the connection factory itself. Thanks for your valuable help.